# word-wrap td content

Tags: css

The content text in 1st td of table is very long, there is no spaces between. Then i applied word-wrap:break-word. but this is not working. Can anybody experience the below problem.
Please suggest the solution.

Here is my Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/F556F/2/

```
<div>
<table border=1 width=100%>
<tr>
    <td>12345678890123456788901234567889012345678890123456788901234567889012345678890</td>
    <td>SECOND</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
div{width:300px}
table tr td{width:50%;overflow:hidden;background-color:#ccc;width:200px;word-wrap:break-word}​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table-layout: fixed` will help you: [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/F556F/6/)

Comment: [table-layout css property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp) or [google for](https://www.google.com/search?q=table+layout+css)

Answer (score 0):

Hi now give to this `text` in `div class` as like this

```
<div>
<table border=1>
<tr>
    <td><div class="ok">12345678890123456788901234567889012345678890123456788901234567889012345678890</div></td>
    <td>SECOND</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

than define `.ok` style

***[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F556F/5/)***

Comment: very nice solution; also you can use `overflow:auto;`.